# Key Value Store in NoSQL Database Systems

Tags: database, key-value-store

Actually, whenever I search for key-value store used in some NoSQL database systems, I encounter the definition like this: "Each value has its own unique key and values are stored depending on their keys."

However, I cannot understand substructure of this database system.

Can we say that key-value store is a hash map in c++, and can the values be primitive types or objects?

Comment: If you have specific question about a particular key-value store create another question and try to ping me...

Comment: Did you look at my answer? Is there something I can do to improve it?

Comment: I am sorry that I have just seen your answer. Your answer is very informative and instructive. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of the kind of key-value store your are talking.

If you take for instance [gdbm](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) it's very comparable to hasmap in C++ except that key and values must be bytes. If you want to store more complicated datastructure you must serialize them. In this kind of database, there is AFAIK not much patterns to use.

There is also **Ordered** key-value stores where the dictionary keys are ordered by key using [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). There is various patterns in this case. They all rely on key composition that is building key in a way to take advantage of prefix search offered by the key-value store and fast next/prev lookup. It also rely on creating multiple key-value pair for a single record.

See my answers on the topic for more information:

- see [How to store list in key-value store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32150072/140837)
- see [Expressing multiple columns in berkeley db in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32148388/140837)
- see [How to give multiple values to a single key using a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32147466/140837)

That said, all those patterns are made much more explicit when using wiredtiger key-value store, see [Schema, Columns, Column Groups, Indices and Projections in wiredtiger documentation](http://source.wiredtiger.com/3.0.0/schema.html)