# Is it possible not to overwrite earlier values in RocksDB?

Tags: rocksdb

For example, the logic for current RocksDB is:

```
put(key1, value1);  
put(key1, value2);
```

And you can find `(key1, value1)` nowhere.

Is there a property or something like it, that can keep the earlier key-value pair like `(key1, value1)` whether in the `memtable` or the SST files?

Comment: You have to create a list see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32150072/140837